# Proving a result related to square prism

Tags: trigonometry

*question*

In the regular quadrilateral prism $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ we denote by $M$ the intersection of the lines $A'C$ and $D'B$. If $AB>A'A$ , prove that

> $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}<\sin(\angle MAD)<\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$

*drawing*

[image]

*my idea*

I'm quite new to these geometries in space problems so I wonder if $M$ is the centre of a regular quadrilateral prism and $A, M, C'$ are colinear too.

We can show that $ABC'D''$ is a rectangle.

If we get a new point called $F$, that is in the middle of AB as
@Joshua Finlayson said in comments.

The thing is I don't know how to calculate each side to express them between $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$

I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Well unless regular means something different in three dimensions, then a regular quadrilateral is a quadrilateral where all sides are of equal length, and angles are equal. This is called a square, so a regular quadrilateral prism is a square prism, so ABCD is a square, and due to being a prism, when it is cut at any point along the length that square should be the cross sectional face. Therefore A’B’C’D’ is also a square as if it is not then when the prism is cut parallel to ABCD right in-front of A’B’C’D’ The cross sectional face would not be a square. So A’B’C’D’ is a square

Comment: @JoshuaFinlayson Isn't it like the definition?

Comment: What makes it a lot easier is to create a new point called $F$, that is in the middle of $AB$, and remember that $sin$ is opposite over hypotenuse. So with point $F$, $sin(\angle MAD) = \frac{FM}{MA}$ and then find FM and MA in terms of $AB$ for the greater side, and $A'A$ for the less side. Quite a fun proof

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry, I read your question wrong when I explained my first comment, but the second comment is accurate

Comment: @JoshuaFinlayson Great idea! But the thing is that we have to show that traingle $MAB$ is issoscels, which means that $D'C'BA$ is a rectangle. How can we show this?

Comment: @JoshuaFinlayson Can you look at the edit and explain me? Thank you!

Comment: Why does it say "bounty for answer"? There is no bounty on this question right now.

Comment: @DavidLui because it doesmt let me start a bounty now  but i will give and start one when it will let me. Just letting people know that their efforts are gling to get ,,paid"

Comment: You don’t need to show, isosceles stuff or anything, I wrote an answer below, all you need is pythag and the knowledge on the geometric properties of a square prism, which you can find easily with an online search

Comment: I would suggest if you can’t figure out the proof, read the first half of my answer and then try to find FM yourself, using the same method

Comment: @ lonela Buciu:  Is it a parallelopiped? Every face a rectangle ?

Comment: @Narasimham No, it's not a parallelopiped. The bases are squares so it is a square prism.

Comment: @Narasimham Yes. We have to show that MAD is between those limits. The answer below proved that is smaller than $54.7356$ and I tried showing in the same way that is smaller than $45$ but it didn't work. Take a look at it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using coordinate geometry, we can write
$$A(0,0,0),B(2a,0,0),C(2a,2a,0),D(0,2a,0)$$
$$A'(0,0,2b),B'(2a,0,2b),C'(2a,2a,2b),D'(0,2a,2b)$$
where $a\gt b$ because $AB>A'A$.

Let $M(p,q,r)$.

Since $M$ is a point on $A'C$, there is a real number $s$ such that $\vec{A'M}=s\vec{A'C}$, i.e.
$$(p-0,q-0,r-2b)=s(2a-0,2a-0,0-2b)$$
So, $$p=2as,q=2as,r=-2bs+2b\tag1$$

Also, $M$ is a point on $D'B$, there is a real number $t$ such that $\vec{BM}=t\vec{BD'}$, i.e.
$$(p-2a,q-0,r-0)=t(0-2a,2a-0,2b-0)$$
So, $$p=-2at+2a,q=2at,r=2bt\tag2$$

From $(1)(2)$, solving
$$p=2as=-2at+2a,q=2as=2at, r=-2bs+2b=2bt$$
gives $s=t=\frac 12$ and $M(a,a,b)$.

Now, let $E$ be a point on $AD$ such that $ME\perp AD$.

Since $\triangle{MAD}$ is an isosceles triangle with $MA=MD$, we have $\triangle{MED}\equiv\triangle{MEA}$ from which $ED=EA$ follows. Since $E$ is the midpoint of $AD$, we get $E(0,a,0)$.

So, we have
$$\begin{align}\sin\angle{MAD}&=\frac{ME}{AM}
\\\\&=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{2a^2+b^2}}
\\\\&=\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2a^2+b^2}}
\\\\&=\sqrt{\frac{(\frac ab)^2+1}{2(\frac ab)^2+1}}
\\\\&=\sqrt{\frac 12+\frac{1}{4(\frac ab)^2+2}}\end{align}$$

Seeing this as a function of $\frac ab$ with $\frac ab\gt 1$, we can see that this is decreasing.

Therefore, we finally get
$$\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}=\sqrt{\frac 12+0}\lt \sin\angle{MAD}\lt \sqrt{\frac 12+\frac{1}{4\cdot 1^2+2}}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}$$

---

**Added** :

This is a solution which does not use coordinate geometry.

Let $F$ be a point on $AD$ such that $MF\perp AD$. Then, we have
$$\sin\angle{MAD}=\frac{FM}{AM}$$

Let us represent $AM,FM$ by $AB,AA'$.

We have
$$\begin{align}AM&=\frac 12 AC'
\\\\&=\frac 12\sqrt{AB^2+BC^2+AA'^2}
\\\\&=\frac 12\sqrt{AB^2+AB^2+AA'^2}
\\\\&=\frac 12\sqrt{2AB^2+AA'^2}\tag1\end{align}$$

ALso, we have
$$\begin{align}FM&=\sqrt{(\frac 12AA')^2+(\frac 12AB)^2}
\\\\&=\frac 12\sqrt{AA'^2+AB^2}\tag2\end{align}$$

From $(1)(2)$, we have
$$\begin{align}\sin\angle{MAD}&=\frac{\frac 12\sqrt{AA'^2+AB^2}}{\frac 12\sqrt{2AB^2+AA'^2}}
\\\\&=\sqrt{\frac{AA'^2+AB^2}{2AB^2+AA'^2}}
\\\\&=\sqrt{\frac{1+(\frac{AB}{AA'})^2}{2(\frac{AB}{AA'})^2+1}}
\\\\&=\sqrt{\frac 12+\frac{1}{4(\frac{AB}{AA'})^2+2}}\end{align}$$

Seeing this as a function of $\frac{AB}{AA'}$ where $\frac{AB}{AA'}\gt 1$, we can see that this is decreasing.

Therefore, we finally get
$$\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}=\sqrt{\frac 12+0}\lt \sin\angle{MAD}\lt \sqrt{\frac 12+\frac{1}{4\cdot 1^2+2}}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4799879/solution-verification-proving-a-result-related-to-prism can you look at this and tell me if its right... it's my idea on how to solve this problem...

Comment: thank you so much. Did you look on the link, is my idea ok?

Comment: Is there anyway yoou can explain the last part without function?

Comment: If we go bacwards we have to show that $\frac{2}{4}<\frac{}1{2}+\frac{1}{4\frac{{AB}{AA'}}^2+2}<\frac{2}{3}$ after some process we got to the fact that $\frac{{AB}{AA'}}^2<1$ which is not real. If  am not wrong, your idea might be wrong...

Comment: @IONELABUCIU : Yes, there is a way we can explain the last part without function. Starting with $(\frac{AB}{AA'})^2\gt 1$, we have $4(\frac{AB}{AA'})^2+2\gt 6$ $\implies$ $\frac{1}{4(\frac{AB}{AA'})^2+2}\lt \frac 16$ $\implies $ $\frac 12+\frac{1}{4(\frac{AB}{AA'})^2+2}\lt \frac 23$ $\implies$ $\frac{FM}{AM}=\sqrt{\frac 12+\frac{1}{4(\frac{AB}{AA'})^2+2}}\lt \frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}$. Starting with $\frac{1}{4(\frac{AB}{AA'})^2+2}\gt 0$, we have $\frac 12+\frac{1}{4(\frac{AB}{AA'})^2+2}\gt \frac 12$ $\implies$ $\frac{FM}{AM}=\sqrt{\frac 12+\frac{1}{4(\frac{AB}{AA'})^2+2}}\gt  \sqrt{\frac 12}$

Comment: Now i understand! Thank you so much! I gave you the bounty!

Answer (score 2):

So as I mentioned in the comments, the three dimensional shape is a square prism, which means that the diagonals bisect each other. at the centre

And by adding point $F$, this creates a point in the triangle $MAD$ that is perpendicular to $AD$

meaning that $sin(\angle MAD) = \frac{FM}{AM}$

as $sin = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$

This means that we just need to find $MA$ and $FM$ in terms of $AB$, and $A'A$.

---

Alright, now that that is out of the way time for the new stuff.

as the diagonals of the prism bisect each other, $AM = \frac{1}{2}AC'$
so then we find AC

$AC = \sqrt{AB^2 + BC^2}$ due to pythag

and so as $AC = A'C'$ due to the shape being a prism
$AC' = \sqrt{\sqrt{AB^2 + BC^2}^2 + A'A^2}$

$AC' = \sqrt{AB^2 + BC^2 + A'A^2}$

and so this is when we use the given, $AB > A'A$

to say that if $AC' = \sqrt{AB^2 + BC^2 + A'A^2}$

then we can substitute $A'A$ with $AB$ to get

$AC' < \sqrt{AB^2 + BC^2 + AB^2}$

$AC' < \sqrt{2AB^2 + BC^2}$

And then due to $ABCD$ being a square $AB = BC$

so we can substitute $BC$ for $AB$ to get:

$AC' < \sqrt{2AB^2 + AB^2}$

$AC' < \sqrt{3AB^2}$

which simplifies to

$AC' < \sqrt{3} * AB$

and then we go back for $AM = \frac{1}{2}AC'$

for $AM < \frac{1}{2}\times\sqrt{3}AB$

$AM < \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\times AB$.

Now, for $FM$, this uses just uses pythag, and the trick before of substituting , $A'A$ for $AB$, so try to find $FM$ and if you can't then read on

---

so if we use create another point called $G$ and put that at the same height of $M$, and directly above $F$,

then we get a right angle triangle $FGM$, so now $GM = \frac{1}{2}AB$, as $M$ is the midpoint.

and $FG = \frac{1}{2}A'A$ as $G$ is halfway up the side because $M$ is the midpoint of the shape.

so $FM^2 = FG^2 + GM^2$

$FM = \sqrt{FG^2 + GM^2}$

substitute in our values for $FG$, and $GM$ to get:

$FM = \sqrt{(\frac{1}{2}A'A)^2 + (\frac{1}{2}AB)^2}$

$FM = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}A'A^2 + \frac{1}{4}AB^2}$

do our substitute $A'A$ for $AB$ trick,

$FM < \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}AB^2 + \frac{1}{4}AB^2}$

$FM < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}AB^2}$

$FM < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\times AB$

$FM < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\times AB$

which can then be rationalised to:

$FM < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

---

Now we have $FM$ and $AM$, so with the definition of $sin$ we can say that:

$sin(\angle MAD) = \frac{FM}{AM}$

substitute our values for what is greater then $FM$ and $AM$ into the equation

$\frac{FM}{AM} < \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\times AB}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\times AB}$

The $AB$s cancel out

$\frac{FM}{AM} < \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$

and then when we do fraction division:

$\frac{FM}{AM} < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\div\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\frac{FM}{AM} < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\times\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$

$\frac{FM}{AM} < \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{3}}$

$\frac{FM}{AM} < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$

so as $\frac{FM}{AM} = sin(\angle MAD)$

$sin(\angle MAD) < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$

---

This is way too long, to write the second part, so you can figure that one out yourself,

you just substitute $AB$ for $A'A$ instead of $A'A$ for $AB$ as was done above

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!!

Comment: Sorry for putting another question, but i tried continuing you idea and I got that $AM>\frac{\sqrt{3}*AA'}{2}$ and that $FM>\frac{AA'*\sqrt{2}}{2}$ which will lead to the wrong answer! Can you please help me again? Thank you!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4799879/solution-verification-proving-a-result-related-to-prism can you look at this... it's the way I continued your answer and tell me if I'm right?

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here?

As $M$ is located in the middle of the cube, you can easily calculate (using Pythagoras) that the distance to whatever point equals $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, so you end up with a isosceles triangle $ADM$, where $|AM| = |DM| = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ while $|AD|$ equals $1$.

[image: Screenshot]

On this triangle, you can easily use the cosine-rule:

$$|MD|^2 = |AD|^2 + |AM|^2 - 2 |AD| |AM| \cos(MAD)$$

$$3/4 = 1 + 3/4 - 2 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot \cos(MAD)$$

This comes down to:

$$ \cos (MAD) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

You can calculate the sine from there.

(Beware: I have written this without verification, so it might contain some calculation errors, but the main idea should be clear.)

Comment: How did you get that $AM=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$?

Comment: Also the figure isnt a cube. $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ is a prism with the bases squares.

Answer (score 0):

Given

$\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}<\sin(\angle MAD)<\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}};$

Taking inverse sine of these angles in the monotone increasing domain/range,it should be proved that:

$ 45^{\circ}<\angle MAD< \angle 54.7356^{\circ} ;$

When M is mid-point of base angles looking at square base horizontal plane

$$ MAD=MBC = 45 ~ deg $$

When $ AA'/AB \to \infty $ or when $ AA',BB',CC',DD' \to \infty$ in length we have in the limit

$$ MAD=MBC = 90 ~ deg $$

It is certain that you are considering the case of a  **CUBE**  of side (edge) length say $2$ and not any other taller or shorter prism on a square base.
As given the relation cannot be proved.

We can prove it  only when ratio of sides in the particular case

$$ AA'/AB =1. $$

Consider the inclined planes $MAD $  or  $ MBPC; $ Let $P$ be mid-point of AD. Consider right triangles in a cube.

[image]

$$ \sin MAD( = MBP) = \frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3} , \angle MAD , 54.7356^{\circ}.$$

As $M$ is displaced upwards the latter does not tend towards $90^{\circ}= \tan^{-1}\infty$ which it should.