# solution verification - Proving a result related to prism...

Tags: inequality, trigonometry, solution-verification

*question*

In the regular quadrilateral prism $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ we denote by $M$ the intersection of the lines $A'C$ and $D'B$. If $AB>A'A$ , prove that

> $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}<\sin(\angle MAD)<\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$

*my idea*

Can you please tell me if my idea is right? I ask this, cause I have a strange feeling that my idea isn't right because I am new to these types of problems.

[image]

by adding point $F$, this creates a point in the triangle $MAD$ that is perpendicular to $AD$

meaning that $sin(\angle MAD) = \frac{FM}{AM}$

as $sin = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$

This means we just need to find $MA$ and $FM$ in terms of $AB$, and $A'A$.

---

Alright, now that that is out of the way, it's time for the new stuff.

as the diagonals of the prism bisect each other, $AM = \frac{1}{2}AC'$
so then we find AC

$AC = \sqrt{AB^2 + BC^2}$ due to pythag

and so as $AC = A'C'$ due to the shape being a prism
$AC' = \sqrt{\sqrt{AB^2 + BC^2}^2 + A'A^2}$

$AC' = \sqrt{AB^2 + BC^2 + A'A^2}$

and so this is when we use the given, $AB > A'A$

to say that if $AC' = \sqrt{AB^2 + BC^2 + A'A^2}$

then we can substitute $A'A$ with $AB$ to get

$AC' < \sqrt{AB^2 + BC^2 + AB^2}$

$AC' < \sqrt{2AB^2 + BC^2}$

And then due to $ABCD$ being a square $AB = BC$

so we can substitute $BC$ for $AB$ to get:

$AC' < \sqrt{2AB^2 + AB^2}$

$AC' < \sqrt{3AB^2}$

which simplifies to

$AC' < \sqrt{3} * AB$

and then we go back for $AM = \frac{1}{2}AC'$

for $AM < \frac{1}{2}\times\sqrt{3}AB$

$AM < \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\times AB$.

Now, for $FM$, this uses just uses pythag, and the trick before of substituting, $A'A$ for $AB$, so try to find $FM$ and if you can't then read on

---

so if we use create another point called $G$ and put that at the same height of $M$, and directly above $F$,

then we get a right angle triangle $FGM$, so now $GM = \frac{1}{2}AB$, as $M$ is the midpoint.

and $FG = \frac{1}{2}A'A$ as $G$ is halfway up the side because $M$ is the midpoint of the shape.

so $FM^2 = FG^2 + GM^2$

$FM = \sqrt{FG^2 + GM^2}$

substitute in our values for $FG$, and $GM$ to get:

$FM = \sqrt{(\frac{1}{2}A'A)^2 + (\frac{1}{2}AB)^2}$

$FM = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}A'A^2 + \frac{1}{4}AB^2}$

do our substitute $A'A$ for $AB$ trick,

$FM < \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}AB^2 + \frac{1}{4}AB^2}$

$FM < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}AB^2}$

$FM < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\times AB$

$FM < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\times AB$

which can then be rationalised to:

$FM < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

---

Now we have $FM$ and $AM$, so with the definition of $sin$ we can say that:

$sin(\angle MAD) = \frac{FM}{AM}$

substitute our values for what is greater than $FM$ and $AM$ into the equation

$\frac{FM}{AM} < \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\times AB}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\times AB}$

The $AB$s cancel out

$\frac{FM}{AM} < \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$

and then when we do fraction division:

$\frac{FM}{AM} < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\div\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\frac{FM}{AM} < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\times\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$

$\frac{FM}{AM} < \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{3}}$

$\frac{FM}{AM} < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$

so as $\frac{FM}{AM} = sin(\angle MAD)$

$sin(\angle MAD) < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$

---

Doing the same thing, like just substitute $AB$ for $A'A$ instead of $A'A$ for $AB$ as was done above we get

$AM>\frac{\sqrt{3}*AA'}{2}$

$FM>\frac{AA'*\sqrt{2}}{2}>A\frac{AA'*\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}*2}$

which shows the requirement.

I am not sure if my idea is okay because if we divide  $FM>\frac{AA'*\sqrt{2}}{2}$ with $AM>\frac{\sqrt{3}*AA'}{2}$ we get that $sin(\angle MAD)>\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$ and we already know that $sin(\angle MAD) < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$

I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Don't yell. [Don't use pictures to convey information not otherwise present in your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I edited it!

Comment: (1) [Joshua Finlayson's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4799063/78967) is not correct since $\frac{FM}{AM}<\frac{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\times AB}{\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\times AB}$ does not follow from $AM\lt\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\times AB$ and $FM\lt \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\times AB$. Note that it follows from $AM\lt\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\times AB$ that $\frac{1}{AM}\color{red}{\gt}\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\times AB}$. (2) This means that your idea does not work. (3) See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4799961/78967). Representing $AM,FM$ by $AB,AA'$ and using $AB\gt AA'$ at the last step works.